# Change Solr Search UI Solritas

Tags: solr, full-text-search, websolr

I am looking to change the Solr Search UI ( Solritas) . The present UI looks like a Retail Electronics Shop UI .

If I would like to modify the UI. Is there any xml file using which I can control the look and feel of the UI .

For example I would like to remove price attribute from the facet searching ( Range Facet) .

**Solution tried :**

Removed price field from  the schema.xml and also the sample Input. But I m still able to find the Range Facet. Please help me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the Solritas UI, edit its Velocity templates in conf/velocity. You can also override specific templates with your own. See http://wiki.apache.org/solr/VelocityResponseWriter for reference.

Additional reference: http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.7/user-guide.html